# create a dictionary contains Array and Dictionary in swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

I just want to create an API JSON Structure. The following are the post body keys and objects. Are there any methods like object with keys and values similar to Objective C in Swift 4?

```
{
    "name": "switch 1",
    "type": "Switch",
    "gatewayId":515,
    "serialKey": "98:07:2D:48:D3:56",
    "noOfGangs": 4,
    "equipments": [
        {
            "name": "light",
            "type": "Light",
            "port": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "television",
            "type": "Television",
            "port": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you can take one dictionary for the your all parameters inside that you can take one array for one of the your parameter "equipments" and set that array as an object for that key.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?  I'm trying to create an empty nested dictionary and I am really struggling.  Neither of these answers have helped me.  I'm moving from Python 3.8 to XCode 11.5 and it's a steep learning curve to figure out how to do what I am doing in Python over in XCode.

Answer (score 10):

You can create the dictionary literally by annotating the type and replace the curly braces with square brackets

```
let dict : [String:Any] = ["name": "switch 1", "type": "Switch", "gatewayId":515, "serialKey": "98:07:2D:48:D3:56", "noOfGangs": 4, "equipments": [[ "name": "light", "type": "Light", "port": "1" ], ["name": "television", "type": "Television", "port": "3" ]]]
```

Or build it:

```
var dict : [String:Any] = ["name": "switch 1", "type": "Switch", "gatewayId":515, "serialKey": "98:07:2D:48:D3:56", "noOfGangs": 4]
var equipments = [[String:String]]()
equipments.append(["name": "light", "type": "Light", "port": "1" ])
equipments.append(["name": "television", "type": "Television", "port": "3" ])
dict["equipments"] = equipments
```

Answer (score 8):

how to create Dictionary

```
var populatedDictionary = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]
```

this how to create Array

```
var shoppingList: [String] = ["Eggs", "Milk"]
```

you can create Dictionary by this type

```
var dictionary =  [Int:String]() 

dictionary.updateValue(value: "Hola", forKey: 1)
dictionary.updateValue(value: "Hello", forKey: 2)
dictionary.updateValue(value: "Aloha", forKey: 3)
```

// anather example

```
var dict = [ 1 : "abc", 2 : "cde"]
dict.updateValue("efg", forKey: 3)
print(dict)
```

your JSON

```
let dic :[String:Any] = ["name": "switch 1", "type": "Switch", "gatewayId":515, "serialKey": "98:07:2D:48:D3:56", "noOfGangs": 4, "equipments": [ [ "name": "light", "type": "Light", "port": "1" ],
                                                                                                                                                      [ "name": "television", "type": "Television", "port": "3" ] ] ]
```

Comment: all these values are initialized at the time of declaration. how can I declare a dictionary globally and add multiple values into the dictionary in button action or a function?

Comment: so you need  mutable Dictionary  or what?

Comment: yes mutable dictionary. Is there any function like "NsDictionary DictionaryWithObjectsandKeys" in swift 3.1. so i can add multiple values into the dictionary in a single line. appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Answer updated check it  dictionary.updateValue(value: "Hola", forKey: 1)

Comment: its works only for just updating single key-value pair. my use case is
GlobalDictionary //declared in class
set values into the globalDictionary via a button click action // add multiple key-value pairs strings, arrays of dictionary's, integers etc.

Comment: I have to send same this kind of parameter dictionary as a post request. I prepared it and send it. Got response of success also but in backend all parameters display null. Dont know what is happen